# how to get variable value is spec statements?

Tags: scala, specifications, scalatest, specs2

I have code like this

```
 "When some call is made, status is (+value+)" in {
        Get("/path") ~> routeToCall ~> check {
           // some statements
           status === OK  <---- this value I want in When Statment
        }
      }
```

whatever status we get OK or Fail, I want it in "when....... status is OK" some thing.

Comment: I understand what you want to do but I'm not sure it is sensible.  It doesn't seem like a spec if it's state cannot be determined ahead of time.

Comment: My understanding is that your test assertion will vary depending on whether the HTTP Response is `2XX` versus `5XX`. If that's true, then why can't you simply use an `if/else`?

Comment: This is the subject of the `specs2-gwt` module. Please have a look at https://etorreborre.github.io/specs2/guide/SPECS2-3.7.1/org.specs2.guide.GivenWhenThenStyle.html

Answer (score 0):

With the `specs2-gwt` module you can write something like

```
class APISpec extends mutable.Specification with 
   org.specs2.specification.dsl.mutable.GWT with   
   StandardDelimitedStepParsers {

   "When some call is made, status is {OK}".example(aString) { expected: String =>
     Get("/path") ~> routeToCall ~> check {
       // some statements
       status === expected
     }
   }
}
```

Please check the [documentation](https://etorreborre.github.io/specs2/guide/SPECS2-3.7.1/org.specs2.guide.GivenWhenThenStyle.html) for more examples.